# Processing remote sensing data

Tags: r, satellite-image

Can anybody help me with my problem?
I want to process ocean color level 2 products using R.
These files contain a *.nc file. I need to reproject the files before processing and then I need to apply some masks and flags to the files.
I would really appreciate it if anyone could direct me to the appropriate resources.

Thank you.

Comment: Both the `stars` and the `raster` package might be very helpful for these operations.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.